# How to query the address? (LINQ to XML)

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
<Copyright>
Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
</Copyright>
<BrandLogoUri>
[http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png]
</BrandLogoUri>
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
<AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
<TraceId>
50230e70257e4ed5a5002a3d4a625c83|LTSM001156|02.00.159.1700|LTSMSNVM001471, LTSMSNVM001477
</TraceId>
<ResourceSets>
<ResourceSet>
<EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
<Resources>
<Location>
<Name>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</Name>
<Point>
<Latitude>47.640568390488625</Latitude>
<Longitude>-122.1293731033802</Longitude>
</Point>
<BoundingBox>
<SouthLatitude>47.636705672917948</SouthLatitude>
<WestLongitude>-122.137016420622</WestLongitude>
<NorthLatitude>47.6444311080593</NorthLatitude>
<EastLongitude>-122.1217297861384</EastLongitude>
</BoundingBox>
<EntityType>Address</EntityType>
<Address>
<AddressLine>1 Microsoft Way</AddressLine>
<AdminDistrict>WA</AdminDistrict>
<AdminDistrict2>King Co.</AdminDistrict2>
<CountryRegion>United States</CountryRegion>
<FormattedAddress>1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052</FormattedAddress>
<Locality>Redmond</Locality>
<PostalCode>98052</PostalCode>
</Address>
<Confidence>Medium</Confidence>
</Location>
</Resources>
</ResourceSet>
</ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

How can I query the locality from address. This text is LINQ to XML object I think.
I tried 
  var asdf = from q in xmlLocation.Elements("Address")
                            select q.Element("Locality").Value;
    but not work, why?

If you know pls write me
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Xml namespaces; since your data is not in the default namespace, you need:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
```

And then use that in all your queries, i.e.

```
var asdf = from q in xmlLocation.Elements(ns + "Address")
           select (string) q.Element(ns + "Locality");
```

Comment: the full part of code is 
  XElement xmlLocation = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

                var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
                var locality= from q in xmlLocation.Descendants(ns + "Address")
                           select q.Element(ns + "Locality").Value;

Comment: @BalázsErdős indeed, if xmlLocation is the entire document, you'll need descendants - that wasn't clear since xmlLocation was never defined :p re the end, I personally prefer (string)element over element.Value, as it avoids null-ref exceptions in a lot of cases and ports nicely to (int)element, (DateTime)element, etc - with LINQ-to-XML performing the appropriate parsing for you (XML date format, for example)

Comment: I understand that, but my query doesn't give back anything. I have a important homework, but I haven't read enough from it yet. Formerly I wrote a LINQ to XML program code, but that was easier the this.  May you write me a good example that I will be able to understand it.

Comment: @BalázsErdős I can try to look later - I'm on mobile at the moment, not ideal for debugging (no compiler!)

Comment: @BalázsErdős look **very carefully** at what was in my `ns`, and indeed Adrian's `ns` - now look at what *you* have given to `ns`. Hint - it *all* matters. Fix that, and it works.

Comment: thx Marc, now It works.
so thx again, in Hungarian "Köszönöm" :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
var asdf = from q in xmlLocation.Descendants(ns + "Address") 
           select q.Element(ns + "Locality").Value;
```